# two docker-compose .yml in the same network with COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to have my own network name for my docker-compose files (server.yml and test.yml), as test.yml gets only started from time to time, but needs access to some services in the server.yml. I can make it work with `docker-compose -p nameofproject up`, but not with COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME.

server.yml

```
version: '2'

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:
  app1:
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepassword
      COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: serverstack

  app2:
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: serverstack
    depends_on:
      - app1
```

My expectation is that when the container is starting I should see

```
Creating serverstackmynetwork_app_1
Creating serverstackmynetwork_app_2
```

the network should be named (`docker network ls`)

```
serverstack_mynetwork
```

just like when I do the following, which actually works

```
docker-compose -p serverstack up
```

And then I can connect just by using `docker-compose up` with the second file (which works just fine when using the -p option on the server.yml)

testing.yml

```
version: '2'

networks:
  testapp_network:
    external:
      name: serverstack_mynetwork

services:
  testapp:
    networks:
      - testapp_network
```

But using it without `-p serverstack` on the server.yml I see directories as names

```
Creating directoryofapp1_app1_1
Creating directoryofapp2_app2_1
```

so `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` is being omitted and I also cannot connect to the server service though serverstack_mynetwork

I did add the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: serverstack` after building the image, but I would expect it should work anyhow. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating the [".env"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#setting-environment-variables-with-docker-compose-run) file containing

`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myprojectname`

Comment: did you need to specify the .env file as an env_file value in all the services defined in your docker-compose.yml file ?

Comment: no, it is not needed to specify the "env_file" option.

Comment: Here is my docker version:

Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be, docker-compose version 1.15.0, build e12f3b9